# python and Json - editing file

Tags: python, json

So, I want to change my info in json file from python, but I am having trouble.
my json file is just info that I want to edit later:

```
[
  {
    "codigo": 10,
    "Nom_articulo": "jabon",
    "valor": 2500,
    "cantidad": 6,
    "subtotal": 0,
    "descuento": 0
  },
  {
    "codigo": 20,
    "Nom_articulo": "Crema",
    "valor": 9800,
    "cantidad": 4,
    "subtotal": 0,
    "descuento": 0
  },
  {
    "codigo": 30,
    "Nom_articulo": "Cepillo",
    "valor": 6000,
    "cantidad": 7,
    "subtotal": 0,
    "descuento": 0
  },
  {
    "codigo": 40,
    "Nom_articulo": "Servilletas",
    "valor": 3000,
    "cantidad": 2,
    "subtotal": 0,
    "descuento": 0
  },
  {
    "codigo": 50,
    "Nom_articulo": "Desodorante",
    "valor": 5000,
    "cantidad": 6,
    "subtotal": 0,
    "descuento": 0
  }
]
```

I want to change the value of "subtotal" in all my dictionaries.

so basically what I did was:

```
for i in range(len(archivo_r)):
                precio= archivo_r[i]["valor"]
                cantidad=archivo_r[i]["cantidad"]
                subtotal=precio*cantidad
                print(archivo_r[i]["codigo"], " - " ,archivo_r[i]["Nom_articulo"], " = ", str(subtotal))
                #almacenar mis subtotales en el archivo json
                print("sbtotal" ,archivo_r[i]["subtotal"])
                archivo_r[i]["subtotal"]=subtotal
                #archivo_r[i]["subtotal"].append(subtotal)
                #print(archivo_r)
            write_json(**XXXXX**)
```

This part of the code:
`archivo_r[i]["subtotal"]=subtotal` does exactly what I need, but (and this could be very silly, but I am a little lost here) I do not know how to use that to re-write my json file. I mean, I have the function to write it.

```
def write_json(info, nombre_archivo="productos.json"):
    with open(nombre_archivo, "w") as p:
        json.dump(info, p)
```

I need to pass the information in  `write_json(**XXXXX**)`, but have been trying to storage my `archivo_r[i]["subtotal"]=subtotal` in a variable to pass it and other things, but nothing work. I know I am doing wrong but not sure how to solve it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Once you're done processing the data, simply pass `archivo_r` to your `write_json()` function and you should be fine.

As an aside, you can iterate directly over the JSON objects like so:

```
for section in archivo_r:
    precio = section["valor"]
    ...
```

You can then replace all instances of `archivo_r[i]` with `section`, or whatever you want to call the variable.